# getting numbers from a textbox that has letters and numbers

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a console based modding application for a PS3 game.

one of the commands goes like

> "kills value"

the value being a number the user defines, How would i only get the "value" of the textbox so it sets the users "kills" to what they defined.

Would it be good to get the value then send it to a label were. After a bit of coding would set the players "kills" to what they defined?

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions would make everything easier.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var input = "kills 67";  // Just an example!
var kill_str = Regex.Match(input, @"\d+").Value;
int kills = Int32.Parse(kill_str);  // Now we have the number specified by our user

// Now, do whatever you want with the collected data
info_label.text = string.format("You specified {0} kills to be added within the hack.", kills);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = "kills value"
var value = input.Split(new char[] {' '})[1];
```